# Access classpath dependencies defined in buildscript block in applied external-script

Tags: java, gradle, build, build-process

My original goal was to be able to use classpath dependencies defined in `buildscript` in `build.gradle`, inside a script that was imported into `build.gradle` using `apply from:`. However, the external script didn't compile since the classes could not be resolved. After researching the issue, I found out that the logic needs to be duplicated and so I thought I would extract `buildscript` into a separate file. Then I would be able to apply that inside `build.gradle` and also inside the external script.

I didn't even get past successfully applying the external buildscript file from `build.gradle`, let alone applying it from the external script. I've tried multiple things, but it seems like I always end up with one of two problems no matter what I try: either properties from `gradle.properties` cannot be used, or the plugin cannot be found (even though the classpath dependency has been defined).

Currently my `gradle/buildscript.gradle` file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://some.url.com" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "my.gradle.plugin:gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
        classpath "my.library:my-library:$libraryVersion"
    }
}
```

`libraryVersion` has been defined in `gradle.properties`. My `build.gradle` is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    apply from: "gradle/buildscript.gradle"
}

apply plugin: 'my.gradle.plugin.PluginClass'
```

When I do this, gradle complains that it cannot find a plugin with id `my.gradle.plugin.PluginClass`. I tried removing the quotes, and I also trying `project.plugin.apply(...)` using the plugin's FQN with and without quotes; both of these caused gradle to error out with a message saying that it could not find the property `my` on the root project.

I also tried:

```
buildscript {
    apply from: "gradle/buildscript.gradle", to: buildscript
}

apply plugin: 'my.gradle.PluginClass'
```

But this causes another error where gradle complains that it cannot resolve `libraryVersion` in `gradle/buildscript.gradle`. So I then tried this:

```
buildscript {
    ext.libraryVersion = "1.0.1"

    repositories {
        maven { url "http://some.url.com" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "my.gradle.plugin:gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
        classpath "my.library:my-library:$libraryVersion"
    }
}
```

Which causes *another* error, where gradle says that there is no such property `ext` on `buildscript`. I understand that this is because there really is no "project" to speak of yet, since `buildscript` is compiled separately. Then I changed my `buildscript` block in `build.gradle` back to:

```
buildscript {
    apply from: "gradle/buildscript.gradle"
}
```

Now I don't get the `ext` error, but I still get an error saying that it cannot find the plugin with the specified id.

I cannot hardcode `libraryVersion` inside `buildscript`, because I need it as a compile-time dependency in `build.gradle` and I'd rather not have to maintain it in two places.

This is extremely confusing and frustrating, because the following `buildscript` block works fine by itself in `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ext.libraryVersion = "1.0.1"

    repositories {
        maven { url "http://some.url.com" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "my.gradle.plugin:gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
        classpath "my.library:my-library:$libraryVersion"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'my-plugin-id' //No need to use FQN

dependencies {
    compile "my.library:library-version:$libraryVersion"
}
```

The reason I tried to split out the `buildscript` block is because I have a file `other.gradle` that has some custom tasks that use classes from `my.library`:

```
import my.library.SomeThing

task customTask(type: DefaultTask) {
    //does something with SomeThing
}
```

But when I leave the `buildscript` block in `build.gradle` and apply the other file like so:

```
buildscript {
    ext.libraryVersion = "1.0.1"

    repositories {
        maven { url "http://some.url.com" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "my.gradle.plugin:gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
        classpath "my.library:my-library:$libraryVersion"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'my-plugin-id' //No need to use FQN

dependencies {
    compile "my.library:my-library:$libraryVersion"
}

apply from: 'gradle/other.gradle'
```

I get an error from gradle saying that it cannot resolve the class `my.library.SomeThing`. I figured I could solve this and avoid duplication by having a common `buildscript` file that I could then apply in both `build.gradle` and `other.gradle`.

I created a custom plugin inside `buildSrc` to configure the project the way I wanted it, only to end up with a more complicated way to fail with the same result. The root cause was the same: there was no way to expose classpath dependencies to external scripts.

Is there comprehensive documentation regarding this sorts of behavior? Everything about this violates the principle of least-surprise. I would expect a `buildscript` block that is being used in `build.gradle` to "just work" when I move it to another file.

The semantics of `apply` with respect to `buildscript` blocks is not clear. In addition, the semantics of `buildscript` itself when it appears in an external file are not clear either - there is a marked variation in behavior, especially with respect to plugins and external properties.

What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Controlling buildscript from an external script is inexplicably complicated/issue-prone in Gradle. See: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2801

Comment: Yeah, I did run into that. The core issue for me is exposing classpath dependencies from the `buildscript` block, to multiple gradle files. Even when doing this in a `buildscript` block in `build.gradle`, it doesn't seem to work. The external files cannot resolve classes that come from the buildscript's classpath.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit of a rant, but there is also a solution. I was able to solve this without using a separate `buildscript` file, but the workaround is unbelievably hackish. I think it's a major downside that you cannot share buildscript dependencies across external scripts.

The problem is that there is no semantic consistency because behavior seems to be dependent on how you decide to organize/modularize your build-logic. If this is a known problem, it needs to be specifically called out in the documentation somewhere - the only way I've been able to find mentions of this sort of surprising behavior is from gradle's own forums or from StackOverflow. I don't think it is unreasonable to expect a build which works with discrete units of build-logic in a single file, to *also* work when those discrete units are split across multiple files. Build logic shouldn't vary based on how you have decided to organize your files, as long as the semantics are consistent.

I understand that there may be technical limitations, but having builds break just because you moved logic from one file into another file is abstraction leakage because now I am required to know details and intricacies of doing so, beyond what one should be *reasonably* expected to know. I wouldn't even mind if this was explicitly and specifically called out, along with solutions/workarounds to bridge the disparity in semantics. However, current documentation regarding organizing build-logic mentions none of these caveats; it only documents the happy path.

/rant

So here's the solution. I saved a reference to the class itself by using extensions:

```
import my.library.SomeThing
import my.library.SomeOtherThing

buildscript {
    ext.libraryVersion = "1.0.1"

    repositories {
        maven { url "http://some.url.com" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "my.gradle.plugin:gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
        classpath "my.library:my-library:$libraryVersion"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'my-plugin-id' //No need to use FQN

ext.SomeThing = SomeThing
ext.SomeOtherThing = SomeOtherThing

dependencies {
    compile "my.library:my-library:$libraryVersion"
}

apply from: 'gradle/other.gradle'
```

Then in `other.gradle`:

```
// Necessary; you can't just use ext.SomeThing in the task later because 
// it is available at compile-time, but apparently not at runtime. Although
// it does work if you use project.ext.SomeThing. However, I just found this
// to be more convenient.
def SomeThing = ext.SomeThing
def SomeOtherThing = ext.SomeOtherThing

task someTask(type: DefaultTask) {
    // You have to use def; you cannot use the actual type because
    // it is not available at compile-time. Also, since you only
    // have a class object, you cannot use "new" directly; you have to
    // create a new instance by calling newInstance() on the class object
    def someThing = SomeThing.newInstance(...)

    // If you are calling static methods you can invoke them directly
    // on the class object. Again, you have to use def if the return
    // type is something defined within my-library.
    def foo = SomeOtherThing.staticMethod(...)
}
```

Comment: +1 For your effort, and agreed on your rant, however things are constantly improving in this aspect of Gradle. Right now it even says in the docs, that buildscript dependencies would be inherited, but I have yet to confirm that ;)